# Why is optimal beam-forming vector w orthogonal to channel signature?

Tags: discrete-signals, beamforming

I am looking at an online document on optimal beam-forming methods: [https://www.comm.utoronto.ca/~rsadve/Notes/BeamForming.pdf](https://www.comm.utoronto.ca/%7Ersadve/Notes/BeamForming.pdf) (sorry I could not find author info from the pdf).

One of the strategies to find optimal beam-forming weights **W** is to use gradient descent for minimal output energy, while keeping the beam forming gain constant. The article provided a block diagram and a brief description of the method attached below:
[image]

It says "*The bottom branch represents the adaptive weights that are chosen such that w ⊥ h0 always.*"

Why though? I wish there's a more elaborate explanation(article is already great!) to help me connect orthogonality of w to channel signature.

Comment: ok I thought more about it if it is not orthogonal then part of the weight **w** would consists of components at original direction + orthogonal to the direction (adding vectors). And the orthogonal part is new info so adding any new "stuff" contributes to the new weight would always boiled down to orthogonal part.